# ¿como incluir jquery en webpack?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack

No se como hacerlo y ya seguí varias explicaciones que encontré por la web y ninguna me funciona. estoy usando `vue-cli` que funciona con `webpack`.

intente con esto:

```
plugins:[
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
  })
]`
```

intente con el **import $ from 'jquery'**

[image: error, con el import de jquery]

me salio ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternativa 1

Puedes importar `jQuery` directamente en el componente que la necesites, solo tienes que instalar la librería con npm o yarn

```
$ npm install --save jQuery
$ yarn add jQuery
```

Solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente en tu componente.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

### Alternativa 2

Puedes importar la librería directamente en tu archivo `índex.html`, como lo harías comúnmente.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero ya hice el import y no me funciona. No se porque

Comment: Sera la alternativa dos

Comment: Recuerda marcar la pregunta como aceptada, __únicamente si esta te fue útil__.

Comment: Gracias todavia no lo he probado

Comment: no me funciona, el error lo publique en la imagen. es extraño porque antes si me habia funcionado

Comment: Agrega debajo de la línea `import` lo siguiente: `console.log($)`. Ocurre que no la usas en ningún lado. Por eso.

Comment: vieras que no es eso. lo que sucede la verdad no entiendo pero estoy usando vue-cli https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli con una plantilla webpack, durante la instalacion me pregunta si quiero usar vue-router y si lo uso no me funciona el import $ from 'jquery'

Comment: le agradezco muchisimo la ayuda que me esta brindando

Comment: tenias razon muchas gracias ya funciona. es lo que ud dijo tenia que usarla sino me marcaba un error.